# Excel VBA - Using GoSub without Return

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation where I'd like to use GoSub within a Subroutine and in *some* situations Return, but in others I would *not* have it Return.  This will be in a large be For Loop and GoSub without Return could happen potentially hundreds of times.  If I do not Return will this build up in memory and cause any issues?

I suppose my question boils down to: does GoSub stack?  And will a large enough stack of un-returned GoSub's cause problems?

If it *does* stack, I can change the code to use GoTo in the instances where I do not  want to Return, but for simplicity's sake I'd rather not.

Also thank you in advance for not lecturing me on GoTo/GoSub not being best practice :)

Comment: Don't do it. Write an actual `Sub` or `Function` instead, then call that. You can predict that behavior trivially. The fact that you ***can't*** do the same with `GoSub` is exactly the reason not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As plenty of others said: **Don't do it**. I am now programming (for a living) since 30 years and never had the need to use GoSub/Return except as a substitute when a programming language didn't provide any subroutines.

That said - I was curious about how VBA handles this. First thing: I assume that there must be a kind of stack. You can have multiple GoSub/Return in one routine and it is handled correctly:

```
Sub testSub1()
    Call StrangeRoutine1
End Sub

Sub StrangeRoutine1()

    GoSub L1
    Exit Sub

L1:
    Debug.Print "Strange1 - L1a"
    GoSub L2
    Debug.Print "Strange1 - L1b"
    Return

L2:
    Debug.Print "Strange1 - L2a"
    Return
End Sub
```

This Prints:

```
Strange1 - L1a
Strange1 - L2a
Strange1 - L1b
```

So the `return` statements jumps after the correct `GoSub` - this is for sure handled with a kind of stack.

However, it seems that this stack is cleared once a Subroutine is left. The following routine has a `GoSub`, but no `Return`. So it leaves an open `GoSub` on the "stack". But when called a 2nd time and issues a `Return` without an `GoSub`, it throws an runtime error 3 "Return without GoSub`.

```
Dim count As Long

Sub testSub2()
    For count = 1 To 2
        Call StrangeRoutine2
    Next
End Sub


Sub StrangeRoutine2()
    If count > 1 Then Return
    GoSub L1
    Exit Sub

L1:
    Debug.Print "Strange2 - L1"
End Sub
```

P.S.: Did i mention it: **Don't do it!**

Comment: I suspect the "stack" is scoped to the procedure, based on the fact that both instructions are required to be in the same procedure. If it did (and allowed jumping into and out of procedures), you'd probably end up trashing the *real* stack.

Comment: Ah ha! It does stack then, okay thank you.  I've run my own test on running a GoSub 50,000 times without using Return, then using Return 10,000 times without calling an additional GoSub and each Return was successful.  As long as one does not call Return more than they have called GoSub it appears to work fine, and does not cause any issues.  My use case will be more like 1,000 maximum, so my 50,000 test shows that it will function correctly - even if it's not best practice ;)

Comment: You can trivially confirm this with `Foo: GoSub Foo`, which results in a runtime error 28 - Out of stack space.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut to see the stack in VBE is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. As you see it does not stack:

[image]

```
Sub GosubDemo()

    GoSub MyRoutine
    Debug.Print "Line before Exiting"
    Exit Sub

GoSomeWhereElso:
    Debug.Print "SomewhereElso I am "
    Return

MyRoutine:
    Debug.Print "My routine"
    GoSub GoSomeWhereElso
    Return

End Sub
```

However, do not use `GoSub` or `GoTo` in VBA. It is considered a very bad practice. `GoTo` could be used for Error Handling like `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`.

- [GoSub ... Return MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/gosubreturn-statement)
- [Dijkstra - GoTo considered harmful](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf)

Comment: The problem in a loop is this (from the MSDN link): "A subroutine can contain more than one Return statement, but the first Return statement encountered causes the flow of execution to branch back to the statement immediately following the most recently executed GoSub statement." If you `GoSub` and ***don't*** `Return`, you can't "clear" your current `GoSub` context. OP's code sounds like a nightmare to debug and maintain.

Comment: I had to write the bad practice sentence in the answer, sry.

Comment: @Comintern - Actually, "nightmare to debug and maintain" usually is how a lot of VBA developers build their code. With integrated "job defence" within it. Then the new developer really wants to cry once he start working with legacy code (I remember I wanted to cry after seeing 5000 lines in 5 subs and 1 function.) And there is no documentation, because "we do not have time for this and the code itself is the best documentation". And yes, there were a lot of GoTo statements there. (Disclaimer - nothing against the OP, most probably the case is different.)

Comment: @Vityata: I feel your pain. I'm going through that right now! Just don't get why **"developers"** can't just split into smaller `functions` or `subs`.. it's a pain going through legacy code!

Comment: Well I was hoping the last sentence in my post would take care of this conversation but I suppose it was inevitable, hahaha.  Thanks for answering my question @Vityata!

Comment: @Zac - that was some years ago, but I still remember it. But until now I am not sure whether it was a "job defence" from the previous guy or he was doing his best actually. Wish you success with the current task.

Comment: @MikeLasch - It was indeed inevitable, its like asking the question "How to convince a junior surgeon not to wash their hands before operation?" and writing in it "I know that washing hands is the best practice.". Glad you have considered my answer helpful. Hopefully you will manage what you need. :)

Comment: See @FunThomas answer below, evidently it does indeed stack, as long as you do not leave the procedure.